# In JAX-RS 2.0, how do I set a property on a FeatureContext from within a DynamicFeature so that the provider being registered can read it?

Tags: jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS 2.0 `DynamicFeature` that registers a response filter on certain classes.

As part of that registration, I'd like the `DynamicFeature` implementation to set a property that can then be retrieved by the filter instance.

It looks like I should be able to do this.  In my `DynamicFeature` implementation, I should be able to call:

```
featureContext.property("foo", "bar");
```

...and it's my understanding that that property is supposed to be durable.

Then, in my filter, I should be able to do:

```
@Context
private Configuration myConfiguration;
```

...and should be able to read that property in my `filter` method:

```
if (this.myConfiguration != null) {
  final Object propertyValue = this.myConfiguration.getProperty("foo");
  if ("bar".equals(propertyValue)) {
    // Hooray
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work.  The `Configuration` instance that is injected into my filter is non-`null`, which is good, but contains one irrelevant property in it that I didn't set.

I know that I could accomplish something similar by using an injected `ServletContext` as the go-between, but I was hoping to avoid using the Servlet APIs here, since this seemed like a "clean" JAX-RS mechanism.

Am I misunderstanding how the `Configuration` object reachable from within a `DynamicFeature`'s `configure` method is to be used?

Comment: This is a bug. Please, file an issue in our [JIRA](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY). As a workaround use `@Inject` to inject the configuration instead of `@Context`.

Comment: @MichalGajdos, thanks for the workaround! it should be the accepted answer.